# Flutter check if string make 2 lines

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to fetch data from my firestore and use that data to show a description text in my widget. The problem is I want the container to have fix size, If the `desc text` exceed 1 line it will have certain height and if its more then 1 line it will have different height.

Can I check if that text create multiline or not in my `container` ? How can I achieve it ?

Comment: u can use according to string length, make sure how many letters u need, and use your 2nd widget if it is over that length

Comment: Which widget did you use to show that text? It'll be easy to handle with TextField or TextFormField widget. Because there has properties for multiline, maxLine, minLine etc. Also, you can style textField to make it like a text widget.